# How to apply function to ALL columns of dataframe GROUPWISELY ? (In python pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

How to apply a function to each column of dataframe "groupwisely" ?
I.e. group by values of one column and calculate e.g. means for each group+ other columns.  The expected output is  dataframe with index - names of different groups, and values - means for each group+column

E.g. consider:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4,4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df['group'] = ['a', 'a', 'b','b']


    A   B   C   D   group
0   0   1   2   3   a
1   4   5   6   7   a
2   8   9   10  11  b
3   12  13  14  15  b
```

I want to calculate e.g. np.mean for each column, but "groupwisely",
in that particular example it can be done by:

```
t = df.groupby('group').agg({'A': np.mean, 'B': np.mean, 'C': np.mean, 'D': np.mean })

    A   B   C   D
group               
a   2   3   4   5
b   10  11  12  13
```

However, it requires explicit use of column names 'A': np.mean, 'B': np.mean, 'C': np.mean, 'D': np.mean
which is unacceptable for my task, since they can be changed.

Comment: `df.groupby('group').mean()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `MaxU` commented simplier is [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`GroupBy.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('group').mean()
print (df1)
        A   B   C   D
group                
a       2   3   4   5
b      10  11  12  13
```

If need column from index:

```
df1 = df.groupby('group', as_index=False).mean()
print (df1)
  group   A   B   C   D
0     a   2   3   4   5
1     b  10  11  12  13
```

Comment: oh wow, how did I not know `as_index` existed until now? This changes everything!

Comment: Thank you very much ! Is there document describing  what can be apllied instead of "mean" ?  I looked over https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html#group-by but there are  no examples like that

Comment: You can use `sum`, `median`, `count`... [Check docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#cython-optimized-aggregation-functions) also.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to explicitly name the columns.

```
df.groupby('group').agg('mean')
```

Will produce the mean for each group for each column as requested:

```
        A   B   C   D
group                
a       2   3   4   5
b      10  11  12  13
```

Answer (score 1):

The below does the job:

`df.groupby('group').apply(np.mean, axis=0)`

giving back

```
          A     B     C     D
group                        
a       2.0   3.0   4.0   5.0
b      10.0  11.0  12.0  13.0
```

`apply` takes `axis = {0,1}` as additional argument, which in turn specifies whether you want to apply the function row-wise or column-wise.

Comment: Not completely sure on this, but I think `apply` will be slower than the standard aggregation methods.

Comment: @asongtoruin You're right, `apply` in these cases is indeed slower than `agg`.